# Having migration scripts, models, controllers and route additions in a rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, migration, routes

i'm developing a modular application on RoR. Ideally, i'd like to make a very generic kernel, and then to be able to code specific plugins around it (Placed in vendor/plugins, or in lib and then only install the ones used by one set-up versus another set-up).

So my question is, is it possible to have any arbitrary model / controller / database migration script in a plugin, as well as additional routes? If it is possible, then how would it be organized in my application's folder hierarchy? Also, if it's possible, it would mean that upon installation, my plugin would have to tell rake to migrate, and upon uninstallation it would have to have some "backup-and-drop" tables logic. How would that be doable?

Thanks a lot,
Pierre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're working with Rails 3, you're describing exactly the behaviour of an engine.

See this gem to easily create yours (and eventually, bundle it as a gem): https://github.com/josevalim/enginex

Comment: isn't any "out-of the box" solution? If i create an "engine" based plugin as you describe, would i require the enginex gem only for development or in production as well (Would my own gem require the enginex)?

Comment: enginex creates a raw & ready to use engine, which you can ut directly in your gemfile

Comment: Thanks a lot for your expertise, i'll be checking that very soon. Is there any good tutorial for creating a plugin from scratch with this generator?

Comment: well, Jose Valim wrote his book... Basically an engine works like a rails app and is included like a gem